# Multi-color text in ASP.NET Button

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css

Wondering if there is a way to have multicolor text for ASP.NET Button Text.
Or what is the best way to have multi-styled text e.g. bold, red-color + normal black color text for ASP.NET button?

One way I know is creating an Image and use ImageButton, which I plan to do if I don't find any other better way.

Any other ways?

**Updated:**

Why need??

1: The button has little informative message and part of the text needs to be differnt for emphasizing.

2: Not my choice.

**One way I figured out**: is using a LinkButton. I'll post my solution once ready.

Comment: From a commercial and user-friendly point of view, this does not make sense, why do you want to achieve that anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
 .btndiv
    {
        border-style: outset;
        background-color: Lime;
        color: Black;
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .btndiv a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }

<p class="btndiv">
    <asp:Linkbutton id="LinkButton1" runat="server"> 
      <span style="color:Red;font-weight:bold">Welcome Back! </span><br /> 
      <span> Click to Enter the site.</span> 
    </asp:Linkbutton>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the XHTML schema allows you to do:

```
<button><span>Hello</span> <span>World</span></button>
```

Which you can style accordingly with CSS.

```
.button span { color: red; }
.button span:first-child { color: blue; }
```

For an ASP.NET button, you could probably write the someting similar, but realistically it is not a great UX recommendation.  If you can keep to a consistent UI, or try to follow the UI guidelines outlined by the parent OS, the user will be more familiar and comfortable.

Comment: ASP.NET Button doesn't allow that. Alternatively I ended up using ASP.NET LinkButton which allows that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you considered using an `<a>` tag instead of a button, 
   and then calling any function on the click event of the  tag?
2. Particletree (written by the guys behind Wufoo forms) has an 
   informative article about styling buttons. 
   http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/
3. Are you sure you want button text with multiple styles? 
   Do you have examples of a well-designed button that has 
   multiple text styles? (I ask because I don't recall ever seeing one...)
4. For reference:

   Apple Mac UX guidelines and buttons: 
   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/XHIGControls/XHIGControls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-TPXREF186

   Windows Vista UX guidelines and command buttons:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511453.aspx